# Pairs comparisons between two lists

Tags: algorithms

This is a little hard to explain, but here goes...

I have a situation that generates two lists of numbers. For simplicity, lets call them two lists of percentages, with each list adding to 100%. For example, one list may be (40%,35%, 25%) {$a_1, a_2, a_3$} and another list might be (55%, 20%, 15%, 10%) {$b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4$}. The two lists are entirely independent and may be any number of values (up to about 20 in either list). I need to pair them up in such a manner that I cover the items of the list in as few pairs as possible, noting that you cannot use multiple items from one list in a 'pair'.

This is probably most easily shown what I mean using my example. In this case, we can do it in five pairs by sight.

Pair one: 40% - a1 and first 40% of $b_1$

Pair two: 15% - first 15% of $a_2$ and last 15% of $b_1$

Pair three: 20% - last 20% of $a_2$ and $b_2$

Pair four: 15% - $b_3$ and first 15% of $a_3$

Pair five: 10% - $b_4$ and last 10% of $a_3$

The question I have is - is there an algorithm I can use to find the lowest number of pairs with any two lists of percentages? If one exists, I will need to convert it into an Excel calculation to cover any scenario. Is there anything close anybody has seen anywhere?

One obvious possible solution is to order the items by size and just match up the result (as I have effectively done in the example).  Is there a better solution?

I should note that a 'pretty good' solution would still be awesome, if not properly satisfying my OCD mathematical purity.

Comment: the numbers are integers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your best bet is, when $a_\max \le b_\max$ to pair $a_\max$ with $b_\max$ leaving behind two new lists $a' = a$ with $a_\max$ removed, and $b' = b$ with $b_\max$ replaced with $b_\max - a_\max$ (or removed if $0$). Then do the same thing with $a'$ and $b'$. etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks...  the numbers are not necessarily integers - I'm curious what differdnce that would make though.  In one of the two lists I can actually have negative numbers, but I think I have decided that I can just treat those as a separate list.  Paul's answer is probably close to optimal, I just wondered if there was any known way of doing this.  It seemed so simple when I first looked at it!

Comment: You will probably not find a polynomial time algorithm which gives you the minimum number of pairs because the problem is NP-hard. Consider an instance of the partition problem given by values $a_1, \ldots, a_n$. Define an instance of your problem by one list containing all the $a_i$ and one list containing two elements of size $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. Then the partition problem has a feasible solution if and only if your problem can be solved by $n$ pairs (otherwise $n+1$ pairs are required).